# RavenDB: .In() and .Where() yielding different results

Tags: ravendb

I have a field, that's indexed as

```cs
Index(x => x.Status, FieldIndexing.Default);
```

in a collection with a total of 2566 records.

Now when I query like this:

```cs
var query = _ravenSession
    .Query<MyIndex.ReduceResult, MyIndex>()
    .Statistics(out stats);

query = query.Where(x => x.Status != "inactive" && x.Status != "invalid" && x.Status != "sold");
```

I get a total result count of 2512.

But if I query like this:

```cs
query = query.Where(x => !x.Status.In("inactive", "invalid", "sold"));
```

I get a total result count of 2520. How can this count be different?

I can see, that the first query translates to

> {((((-Status:inactive AND Status:*) AND -Status:invalid))
>   AND -Status:sold)}

and the second one:

> {(*:* AND -@in`<Status>:(inactive , invalid , sold) )}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference with how this query is processed.
In the first case, you are allowing only results that have a `Status`, in the second, you are saying everything but those particular values. So if you have values that don't have the status property, that might explain it.

Comment: Thanks. From a C# perspective, these 2 expressions should be the same. And I'm not that deep into Lucene-syntax, which threw me off. If I understand you correctly, the first query (when processed) implicitly includes a null-check. And I did indeed have null-values on the field for a few records